# relative risk calculation when a cell is 0

Tags: statistics

the problem wants me to calculate the relative risk, but the dataset is like this

```
2   40

0   18
```

so the rr is $\frac{2}{42}/ \frac{0}{18} = \infty$.

I thought a possible remedy is to add 0.5 to each cell on line 2. Is this a reasonable way?

Comment: What are the meanings of the numbers ? In general it is possible that $rr\to \infty$

Comment: Not a lot to work with here.  Assuming this table plays the role of the table in this article on [Relative Risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_risk) then, the answer is $\infty$, just as you say.  What's wrong with that?  The bad event is impossible in one category, possible in the other.  Granted, in that case relative risk may not be the most descriptive measure.